# LPD6803 led with FastSPI_led library

Tags: arduino

I'm a Arduino newbie looking for help.

I've got a sketch that turns 60 LPD6803 ledpixels into a clock.
The sketch is not very stable and I was told to use a different library.
FASTSPI_led should be lots faster.
The sketch reads a RTC and turns the corresponding led's on in a specific color:

- Red for minutes
- green represent hours
- blue for seconds.

The brightness is also controlled by a LDR. For example, the sketch uses the following line in the loop to set the (hour) led.

```
strip.setPixelColor(h, 0, 0, brightness);
```

h = led number, brightness the green level as in RGB.

The lib from Adafruit is quit easy to use for this sketch!

But now for the problem...
I'm looking at the FastSPI_led lib and can't figure out how to change my code. I managed to come this far, but array's, structs and variables is beyond my league! I need a bridge between my code and the lib. Basically, what I want to achieve is having the same principle, but using the FastSPI_led lib. I've been staring at it but don't see how-to. I'm desperately looking for someone who's willing to help me out on this one. The FastSPI_led lib can be found at [Google].
The entire sketch can be found here.

Answer (score 1):

I also have an issue controlling more than 344 [LEDS modules with LPD-6803 drivers](http://www.ledlightinghut.com/12mm-lpd6803-digital-intelligent-rgb-led-pixels.html).  I've been using the fastspi led library to accomplish this (http://code.google.com/p/fastspi/) for a bit but now that I've added a few more modules and gone over 344 the code appears to halt.  At 344 everything works as intended but any number over this causes none of the commands to be sent out of the arduino.